# Highlight search text in mysql php search

Tags: php, mysql, search, highlight

hi this is the script i have, it works well to search my database.
i have a **form.html** where the user inputs the keyword in a search box.

```
<form method="get" action="form.php">
<input type="text" name="searchterm" title="Enter your search term here" value="Enter your search term here" class="searchbox" />
<input type="submit" name="search" title="Search Now! "value="Search" class="searchbutton" />
</form>
```

**i would like to highlight the search text in the result.**

many thanks

**form.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Search</title>
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
<?php

// include MySQL-processing classes

require_once 'mysql.php'; 

try{

// connect to MySQL

$db=new MySQL(array('host'=>'','user'=>'','password'=>'','database'=>''));

$searchterm=$db->escapeString($_GET['searchterm']);

$result=$db->query("SELECT * FROM BookPage WHERE (PageText) like \"%$searchterm%\" ");

if(!$result->countRows()){

echo '<div class="maincontainer"><h2>No results were found. Go back and try a new search.</h2></div>'."n";

}

else{

// display search results

echo '<div class="maincontainer"><h2>Your search criteria
returned '.$result->countRows().' results.</h2>'."n";

while($row=$result->fetchRow()){

echo '<div class="rowcontainer"><p><strong>Book Id:
</strong>'.$row['BookId'].'<p><p><strong>Page Id:
</strong>'.$row['PageId'].'</p><p><strong>Page Text:
</strong>'.$row['PageText'].'</p></div>'."n"; 

}

}

echo '</div>';

}

catch(Exception $e){

echo $e->getMessage();

exit();

}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$searchvalue = implode('<span style="color:green;font-weight:800;">'.$_GET['searchterm'].'</span>',explode($_GET['searchterm'],$row['PageText']));
echo '<div class="rowcontainer"><p><strong>Book Id:
</strong>'.$row['BookId'].'<p><p><strong>Page Id:
</strong>'.$row['PageId'].'</p><p><strong>Page Text:
</strong>'.$searchvalue.'</p></div>'."n";
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code :

```
<?php
 //$keyword -> keyword to be search in string.
 //$field   -> string contain value to be seach
 // Returns HTML content with highlighted text
function makeHighlighter($keyword, $field) {
    $i = strripos($field, $keyword);
    if ($i !== false) {
        $keyword = str_ireplace($keyword, substr($field, $i, (strlen($keyword))), $keyword);
    } else {
        return $field;
    }
    $as_unm_split = explode($keyword, $field);
    $string_hig = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($as_unm_split); $i++) {
        if ($i < count($as_unm_split) - 1)
            $string_hig.=$as_unm_split[$i] . "<span style=\"color: red\">" . $keyword . "</span>";
        else
            $string_hig.=$as_unm_split[$i];
    }
    unset($as_unm_split, $keyword, $i);
    return $string_hig;
}

echo makeHighlighter("keyword","this is keyword to be match...");
?>
```

O/P

this is **keyword** to be match...
[Note : "keyword"  will be in RED color]

Comment: It doesn't work for utf-8 characters. For example `qué`. How can I improve it to make it work?