# PHP highlight search terms in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

i have this search code:

```
<?php
//members
$sql="SELECT * from members WHERE ";
$sql.="forename LIKE '%".$_GET["s"]."%' OR ";
$sql.="surname LIKE '%".$_GET["s"]."%' ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0)
{
    echo '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><h3>Members</h3></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Member Name</strong></td>
        <td><strong>D.O.B</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Age</strong></td>
      </tr>';
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        //work out the age of each member
        $sql2="SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,CONCAT(dob_year, '-', dob_month, '-', dob_day),CURDATE()) as years, (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,CONCAT(dob_year, '-', dob_month, '-', dob_day),CURDATE()) - TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,CONCAT(dob_year, '-', dob_month, '-', dob_day),CURDATE())*12) as months FROM members where sequence = '".$result["sequence"]."' ";
        $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn);
        $result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2);

        //date in mm/dd/yyyy format; or it can be in other formats as well
         $birthDate = "12/17/1983";
         //explode the date to get month, day and year
         $birthDate = explode("/", $birthDate);
         //get age from date or birthdate
         $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $birthDate[0], $birthDate[1], $birthDate[2]))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y")-$birthDate[2])-1):(date("Y")-$birthDate[2]));

         $forename = implode('<strong>'.$_GET['s'].'</strong>',explode($_GET['s'],$result['forename']));
         $surname = str_replace($_GET["s"], '<font color="#FF0000">'.$_GET["s"]."</font>", $result['surname']);
         echo '<tr class="notfirst" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.location=\'/members/edit_member.php?seq='.$result["sequence"].'\'">
        <td> '.$forename.' '.$surname.'</td>
        <td>'.$result["dob_day"].' / '.$result["dob_month"].' / '.$result["dob_year"].'</td>
        <td>'.$result2["years"].' years / '.$result2["months"].' months</td>
      </tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

i want to highlight the search terms in my results

as you can see i have tried to do this by using:

```
$forename = implode('<strong>'.$_GET['s'].'</strong>',explode($_GET['s'],$result['forename']));
```

and

```
$surname = str_replace($_GET["s"], '<font color="#FF0000">'.$_GET["s"]."</font>", $result['surname']);
```

but its not working - whats the best way to achieve this. i want it to work on both forename and surname results

i tried using the code from: [Highlight search text in mysql php search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175802/highlight-search-text-in-mysql-php-search)

Comment: @ComFreek thank you but thats not helping with my question

Comment: On SQL injections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php  and on MySQL deprecated extensions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Answer (score 0):

First fix sql injection problem then.

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['s']);
$text = str_replace($search,"<b>$search</b>",$textFromMysqlResult); 
echo $text;
```

Comment: i have tried $forename = str_replace($_GET["s"],'<b>'.$_GET["s"].'</b>',$result["forename"]); then echoing the $forename variable in my results but it doesnt work

Comment: i have also just tried $member_name = str_replace($_GET["s"],'<strong>'.$_GET["s"].'</strong>',$result["forename"].' '.$result["surname"]); and then echoing $member_name but still not working

Comment: You mean $forename = str_replace($search,"<b>$search</b>",$forename);
Not works ???
Please view page source.

Comment: just checked page source and there is no <b> around the searched for text