# Highlight search term in mysql php search

Tags: php, mysql, search, highlight

Could someone please help me to highlight the searchterm in my php search code?
Below is the code that I am currently using, and it works fine. Would just like to add a highlight function but have no idea how to implement that on this code without redoing the whole thing.

I came across [Highlight search text in mysql php search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175905/3203051) thispost which looks very nice. But I'm lost trying to implement this. Some time ago I had a `<span>` effect, but couldn't get it into the `<table>` to highlight only the searchterm and still loop through the table.

```
include("config/config.php");
$con = mysql_connect($host, $db_user, $db_pass);
if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

mysql_select_db($db, $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE `data_id` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `who` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `ref` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `asset` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `make_model` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `serial` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `os` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `swp` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `ea` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `dt_in` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `status` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `dt_out` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "<center>";
echo "<BR><BR>";
echo "<a href='index.php'><button id='sblogloginbtn' name='login' type='submit'><b>BACK</b></button></a>";
echo "<BR><BR>";
echo "<h1>Your search has found&nbsp;";
echo "<b><font size='15' color='blue'>$num_rows</font></b>";
echo "&nbsp;records.</font></h1>";
echo "<BR><BR>";

echo "<table border='frame'>
<tr style='color:#FF00FF'>
<th>Signed in By</th>
<th>Reference Number</th>
<th>Asset Number</th>
<th>Make Model</th>
<th>Serial Number</th>
<th>Operating System</th>
<th>Office</th>
<th>Profile</th>
<th>Extra Apps</th>
<th>Time IN</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Time OUT</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['who'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ref'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['asset'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['make_model'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['serial'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['os'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['office'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['swp'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ea'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['dt_in'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['dt_out'] . "</td>";
    }
echo "</table>";
echo "<br /><br />";
echo "</center>";

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to avoid them](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: @Gumbo how can this code be vulnerable to sql injections if its only doing a query to select, no insert, no update nothing. no change on database side. I am asking because i have been trying to find the problem, and i only see the issue being when there is INSERT or UPDATE to database involved.

Comment: [SQL injections are not restricted to just INSERT and UPDATE statements but can happen in any statement.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15732682/53114) In this case it’s `$_POST['searchterm']` that used in MySQL string literals without proper escaping.

Comment: @Gumbo Would this then work?
`$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[searchterm]);`

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/str_replace) to replace the search term with `<span>` tags wrapped around them, styled.

**Warning:** The way you have your script set up, you're vulnerable to injection attacks. This is just an example to show you how to pass in variables.

See: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

```
<?php

include("config/config.php");
$con = mysql_connect($host, $db_user, $db_pass);
if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

mysql_select_db($db, $con);

$term = $_POST[searchterm];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE `data_id` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `who` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `ref` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `asset` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `make_model` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `serial` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `os` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `swp` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `ea` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `dt_in` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `status` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
OR `dt_out` LIKE '%$_POST[searchterm]%'
");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "<center>";
echo "<BR><BR>";
echo "<a href='index.php'><button id='sblogloginbtn' name='login' type='submit'><b>BACK</b></button></a>";
echo "<BR><BR>";
echo "<h1>Your search has found&nbsp;";
echo "<b><font size='15' color='blue'>$num_rows</font></b>";
echo "&nbsp;records.</font></h1>";
echo "<BR><BR>";

echo "<table border='frame'>
<tr style='color:#FF00FF'>
<th>Signed in By</th>
<th>Reference Number</th>
<th>Asset Number</th>
<th>Make Model</th>
<th>Serial Number</th>
<th>Operating System</th>
<th>Office</th>
<th>Profile</th>
<th>Extra Apps</th>
<th>Time IN</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Time OUT</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . str_replace($term, "<span class=\"highlight\">$term</span>", $row['who']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . str_replace($term, "<span class=\"highlight\">$term</span>", $row['ref']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . str_replace($term, "<span class=\"highlight\">$term</span>", $row['asset']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . str_replace($term, "<span class=\"highlight\">$term</span>", $row['make_model']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . str_replace($term, "<span class=\"highlight\">$term</span>", $row['serial']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . str_replace($term, "<span class=\"highlight\">$term</span>", $row['os']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . str_replace($term, "<span class=\"highlight\">$term</span>", $row['office']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . str_replace($term, "<span class=\"highlight\">$term</span>", $row['swp']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . str_replace($term, "<span class=\"highlight\">$term</span>", $row['ea']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . str_replace($term, "<span class=\"highlight\">$term</span>", $row['dt_in']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . str_replace($term, "<span class=\"highlight\">$term</span>", $row['status']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . str_replace($term, "<span class=\"highlight\">$term</span>", $row['dt_out']) . "</td>";
    }
echo "</table>";
echo "<br /><br />";
echo "</center>";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

And some sample styling:

```
<style type="text/css">
.highlight { background-color: yellow; }
</style>
```

Comment: You could make this simpler / more readable by storing everything that you echo in the while loop into a variable, then execute the replace on that variable, then echo the variable.

Comment: I edited your answer to fix a typo and to add a link to "How to prevent SQL injection", but you did another edit at the same time. I'm not going to re-edit.

Comment: You're welcome, however the link is not showing up now, because your edit overwrote mine. If you want to add it again, see the edit history; it's in there.

Comment: with this i get a parse syntax error (syntax error, unexpected ';' in /.../.../.../.../search.php on line 64) the while($row is line 61

Comment: @josh i have no idea where this unexpected ; is

Comment: @user3203051 oops, sorry, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

i dont see where you are printing the searchterm on your page.  also,  I would use css style sheets,  avoid font tags,  for example

```
 <style>

 .searchTerm{
    background-color:red;
    } 
 </style>


 <table>
   <tr><th>You searched for<div class='searchTerm'><?php echo $_POST[searchterm];?></div></th></tr>
  //rest of page
```

Comment: the printing of the search term happens in the table in that code. did not actually highlight it as i did not know now to. %$_POST[searchterm]%. my styling is allready done, in a css file, but did not know how to implement it. The font tag is only to change the color and size of the amount of records the search term found.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a regex (`preg_replace`) to search for your term and replace it with said term surrounded with `<span>` `</span>`.

Look at the documentation of `preg_replace` for how to use it: https://www.php.net/preg_replace

Comment: I don't think there's any need for `preg_replace()` since OP will always know what the search term is. `str_replace()` seems perfectly OK.